# python save file dialogue using tkinter library

Tags: python, tkinter

I created my first python GUI using `tkinter` library, all goes smoothly except when I want to save the file.
The app basically opens a word document, edit some text then save the edited file. It saved perfectly with the code below:

```
file_name = "{}".format(save_entry.get())
save_filename = file_name + '.docx'
word_document.save(save_filename)
```

But I wanted to use `askopenfilename`, as it enables me to specify the file location.

Here is my attempt, using the argument `initialfile`, it saves an empty doc file, not the edited one.

```
filedialog.asksaveasfile(initialfile=word_document.save(save_filename), filetypes=[("Word Document Files", "*.docx"), ("All Files", "*.*")])
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem I faced was using `askopenfilename` creates an empty `docx` file, and not reflecting the update made on that file. So, referring to the [Tkinter Dialogs documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/dialog.html) there is another dialog to select a directory only.

I used it with the code above and now it works as needed.

```
file_name = "{}".format(save_entry.get())
save_filename = file_name + '.docx'
directory = filedialog.askdirectory()
word_document.save(directory+'/'+save_filename)
```